# Getting the value of current row & store it for future use?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using datatables to show data from a mySQL database. What I want to do is capture the value of the current row and show it in a modal for editing.

This is how I am getting the data into Datatable,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#loading-span7').fadeOut();
                $('#loading-span5').fadeOut();
                $('#add-company').hide();

                $.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';

                $('#company').dataTable({
                    "bProcessing" : true,
                    "bServerSide" : true,
                    "sAjaxSource" : "/index.php/company/profile_data",
                    "sDom" : "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                    "sPaginationType" : "bootstrap",
                    "aoColumns" : [{
                        "mData" : "id"
                    }, {
                        "mData" : "name"
                    }, {
                        "mData" : "package_id"
                    }, {
                        "mData" : function(oObj) {
                            return "<a href=\"#\" data-id=\"" + oObj.id + "\" data-name=\"" + oObj.name + "\" role=\"button\" class=\"btn edit-company\">Edit</a></td>";

                        }
                    }, {
                        "mData" : function(oObj) {
                            return "<a href=\"#\" data-id=\"" + oObj.id + "\"  data-name=\"" + oObj.name + "\" role=\"button\" class=\"btn view-users\" >Users</a></td>";
                        }
                    }]
                });

                $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
                    "sWrapper" : "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
                });
```

And here is the modal,

```
<div id="edit_company" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                ×
            </button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel"><span id="company-label"></span>Company</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="company-form">
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…" name="company-name">
                    <label>Package</label>
                    <select name="package" name="package-id" id="package-id">

                    </select>

                </fieldset>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                Close
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                Save changes
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the script that I tried to achieve the goal, the problem however is only the first row of the datatable gets captured into the modal

```
$('#company .edit-company').live('click', function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    $('#company-label').html('Edit ');
                    $('#company-form')[0].reset();
                    $.ajax({
                        url : '/index.php/company/profile_data',
                        type : 'POST',
                        data : 'companies[]=' + id,
                        beforeSend : function() {
                            $('#loading-span7').show();

                        },
                        success : function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

                            var details = JSON.parse(data);
                            console.log(details);
                            //console.log(details.aaData[0].homepage_url);
                            $('input[name=company-name]').val(details.aaData[0].name);
                            //$('input[name=package-id]').html(details.aaData[0].package_id);

                            /**oTable.$('.edit-company').click(function() {
                                var data1 = oTable.fnRowSelected(this);
                                $('input[name=company-name]').val(details.aaData[0].name);

                            });**/
                            var option1 = $('<option />', {
                                text : details.aaData[0].package_id
                            }), option2 = $('<option />', {
                                text : details.aaData[1].package_id
                            });

                            $('select#package-id').append(option1, option2);
                            //$('select#package-id option').text(details.aaData[0].package_id);

                            //$('#package-id').val(details.aaData[0].package_id);
                            $('#edit_company').modal('show');
                            $('#loading-span7').fadeOut();
                        },
                        error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            //alert('error');
                        }
                    });

                });
```

What can I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: do you want to display extra data into your modal, or the existing one from the row?

Comment: The existing one from the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `bServerSide`, just use the `fnRowCallback` and format your columns slightly differently.

```
"fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    var row = $(nRow),
        a = $('<a />').addClass('btn').attr({
            'href': '#',
            "role": "button"
        }).data('rowData', { //store the data in the button
        "id": aData[0],
        "name": aData[1],
        "package_id": aData[2]
    });
    // or store the raw data in the tr element
    //row.data('rowData', aData);
    // or store a formtted object containing the raw data in the tr element
    //row.data('rowData', );
    // Add the Edit button when the datatable draws the row.
    row.find('td:eq(3)').append(a.clone().addClass('edit-company').text('Edit').click(function (e) {
        var self = $(this),
            rowData = self.data('rowData'),
            id = rowData.id,
            name = rowData.name,
            package_id = rowData.package_id;
        //code to init your dialog
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }));
    // Add the Users button when the datatable draws the row.
    row.find('td:eq(4)').append(a.clone().addClass('view-users').text('Users').click(function (e) {
        var self = $(this),
            rowData = self.data('rowData'),
            id = rowData.id,
            name = rowData.name,
            package_id = rowData.package_id;
        //code to handle your users
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }));
},
"aoColumns" : [{
    "mData" : "id"
}, {
    "mData" : "name"
}, {
    "mData" : "package_id"
}, {
    "mData" : "Edit"
}
}, {
    "mData" : "Users"
}]
```

Comment: This seems to be bit complicated, is there any other simple one?

Comment: @user1890338: Sorry. I don't know of anything less complicated but truth be told, the steps are simple. 1. Redefine your `aoColumns` so that you're not creating the buttons there. 2. In `fnRowCallback` store the row data in an element that is being appended to the DOM and create/append your buttons as well.

Comment: Looks like I have to dig in this a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the fnGetData method.

Assuming your table have been set to oTable

```
var oTable = $('#company').dataTable({
                "bProcessing" : true,
                "bServerSide" : true,
                "sAjaxSource" : "/index.php/company/profile_data",
                "sDom" : "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                "sPaginationType" : "bootstrap",
                "aoColumns" : [{
                    "mData" : "id"
                }, {
                    "mData" : "name"
                }, {
                    "mData" : "package_id"
                }, {
                    "mData" : function(oObj) {
                        return "<a href=\"#\" data-id=\"" + oObj.id + "\" data-name=\"" + oObj.name + "\" role=\"button\" class=\"btn edit-company\">Edit</a></td>";

                    }
                }, {
                    "mData" : function(oObj) {
                        return "<a href=\"#\" data-id=\"" + oObj.id + "\"  data-name=\"" + oObj.name + "\" role=\"button\" class=\"btn view-users\" >Users</a></td>";
                    }
                }]
});
var selected_data='';
$("td").live("click", function(){
    selected_data = oTable.fnGetData(this);
});
```

[Exemple here](http://live.datatables.net/ijirif/edit#javascript,html)

Comment: How can I set my table to oTable? I guess it is not.

Comment: What if I want to capture just one cell and show it in a modal?

Comment: You can guess from the Modal what I am actually trying to do.

Comment: then just parse the selected_data with a loop

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this is I have a function that creates the modal, I've simplified it a bit.

```
  function fnModalDetails ( nTr ) {
      var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
      var sOut = '<div id="myModal2" class="reveal-modal large">;
      sOut += aData[1];
      sOut += '</div>';
      return sOut;
  }
```

You need to attach a click handler to your cell somehow.  Below I'm using the Zurb Reveal modal.  You need to remove any modal that might be previously created.

```
  $('.more').live('click', function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
      $('#myModal2').remove();
      $('body').append(fnModalDetails(nTr));
      $("#myModal2").reveal({animation: 'fade'});
  });
```

Hope this helps.